# CKeditor uploads in Struts2

Tags: struts2, ckeditor

I have specified in struts.xml all the options for editor:

```
<constant name="struts.ckeditor.allowUploads" value="true" /> <!-- default is false -->
<constant name="struts.ckeditor.allowedFileExtensions" value="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" />
<constant name="struts.ckeditor.uploadFolder" value="/userfiles/images/" />
```

and added attribute "uploads="true"",

but the server doesn't appear, as in the example on the oficial page of it http://ckeditor.com/demo, only the "Send to Server" button persist.

And why the default upload folder in the input is still "uploads/" if I specified it in the config file as "/userfiles/images/"?

[screehsot http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/7673/screenshotat20120228100.png](http://img141.imageshack.us/img141/7673/screenshotat20120228100.png)

I missed something?

Comment: <constant name="struts.ckeditor.uploadFolder" value="/imageUploads" />
but It's taking the default value "/uploads"; debug whether it's taking configured value or not.